# “How to fix ‘1 positional argument but 3 were given’ error in Python”

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import telebot

token = "8xxxxxxx7:AAElU-XhG1of3VaZMexdDIE-M2aY71CRIFk" 
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
bot.send_document(5xxxxxxx4, open(file.txt, 'rb'))
```

> TypeError: send_document() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Comment: `.send_document` only takes `self` as an argument. Therefore, to pass arguments correctly, you'd need to just `bot.send_document()` (`bot` is `self`, that is exactly 1 argument). But as @vurmux says in their answer, it will break again because the method is not implemented in the base class, you need to inherit from it and implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send_document` [is not implemented](https://github.com/KyleJamesWalker/telebot/blob/414a346357d4f474cdaf6d843c812454b20d2456/telebot/__init__.py#L165) in the base Telebot class:

> ```
> def send_document(self):
>     raise NotImplemented("send_document needs work")
> ```

So if you want to use it, you should create the derived class and implement it manually.

Comment: What i can write?? This?
`def send_document(self):
    raise NotImplemented("send_document needs work")`

Comment: You should use `send_message` or write the new class that is derived from `TeleBot`